# Preveting distribution of java desktop application

Tags: java, security, netbeans, derby

I have developed a **desktop based application** in **Java** using **derby** as the database. The IDE that i am using is **Netbeans.** I am just on the verge of the deployment of the application on the client's machine. I thought of a scenario if the client takes the application developed to some other client like him, he just have to copy paste the application and the database and the application works for him too. By this the application can be distributed a number of times. Is there anything i can do this to stop the unauthorized distribution of the application? How can i register the application on one system? I think its a great mater of **security** of the application. Also i searched the internet and found the problem of decompilation of java code. How can i prevent it. Being new on this i really have no ideas. Any type of advised, links would be welcomes form the experts on stack.

Thanks

Comment: If you distribute the binaries - you cannot 100% protect you application from crack. That is how it is. The only way - server based approach. When you have main functionality running on server and handle users registration/authentication on server.

Comment: Even if you do authentication on the server the cracker may just disable it after decompiling your java code. As other people have posted here, you would be safer if some important (business) functionality is done on the server only.

Comment: @vitaly I write about it in my comment. Please read carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent copying, what you can do is make it less useful or not work unless it is registered.  This way a copied software can be a free demo which might encourage new clients to buy your software (i.e. make it work for you)

A simple way to do this is to have the application check your server if it is registered, even better place some of your key functionality on a server so it cannot be run with the client alone.

You can't prevent de-compiling or reverse engineering, but again if you have a central server it can't be decompiled and reverse engineering it is harder.

BTW: You should look at how the gaming industry solves this problem as it is very common issue and they use lots of interesting solutions.

Comment: in case i don't have a central server would it still be possible to protect it otherwise?

Comment: You can obfuscate the code, and place legal restrictions.  Some people  create a registration key based on the MAC and system information but all of this can be spoofed, so it only offers protection most of the time.  I protected my software from reverse engineering by making it open source ;)

Comment: can i try my own pc with the authentication process just like a server. I have to be online with it when the registration is to be done else, when the system is off if the software is tried on some other machine it wont start. What do say of this?

Comment: It depends on whether your users would like to run the program while off line.  You could have the software, run if registered as long it has checked in the last N days.  If the user is not registered, I would run the software but encourage them to buy the software. e.g. on the splash screen, change the title to (Unregistered) and limit some functionality if it's not registered.

Comment: This way new users can learn to use the software and might buy it later to get registered. Or you could make it new users can run for a month, after that the software doesn't work.